# Change TextView text in included/partial layout

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to change the text from **partial_layout.xml (3)** programmatically through **onCreate** in my created **MainActivity.kt (2)** class. I still need to use the existing **fragment.xml (1)** for some reason. I cannot override the super fragment class, so the only thing I can do is to **include** layout that I created in the **fragment.xml**.

**1. fragment.xml**

```
...
<include layout="@layout/partial_layout.xml" />
...
```

**2. MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity: SuperActivity() {
  ...
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.testString).text = "Some new text"
  }
...
```

**3. partial_layout.xml**

```
...
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/testString"
  android:text="Test"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
...
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve.

Here is the error that occured,
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: show more code, whole `onCreate`/`onCreateView`

Comment: @snachmsm there's nothing much sir, its an override method from the super class

Comment: You didn't call `setContentView`. Without it your activity is empty.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lack of layout set for your `SuperActivity`

```
class MainActivity: SuperActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment)

    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.testString).text = "Some new text"
  }
```

at first you need to call `setContentView` for setting XML to be parsed by `Activity` (and further drawn), then you can use `findViewById` method (without `setContentView` call there is nothing to find)